# Why Visual Studio 2010 publish website with source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, publish, precompile

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with the new website publish dialog. I have a Web Application website. When published, in theory it should compile all the code into an single assembly. However, in both `Debug` and `Release`, after publishing the directory always contains source code of page and user controls (even with the untransformed web.config files Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.Config). This is very confusing.

But with `package/publish web` project configuration and `Generate Deploy package` context menu item, the Package\PackageTmp directory is clean.

- Why doesn't Visual Studio use this Package to publish the website?
- Where is the precompile option?
- Web.config xml transform seems not work, why does Visual Studio bring this feature to confuse me?

Comment: Is it a web application or a web site?  Do you see only `.as?x` files or also `.cs` files?

Comment: @SLaks I'm sure it's Web Application not Web site.I already solved,just because I set `Include all project files` in `Package/Publish web` configuration

Comment: hi @RocHo me too have the same problem but the thing is i am publishing the WEBSITE and not the webapplication in VS2013 Professional Edition. When i publish it also publish the SOURCE CODE and not jst the binaries/dll. So, will u please suggest me any solution to publish files in .aspx/.dll files only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct answer is to look in the Package/Publish Web settings (in the web application project properties) and look for the "Items to deploy".

[image]

For a web application you'd want "Items to deploy" to have "Only files needed to run this application" which would NOT copy the source code files, since they've been compiled into the DLL in the bin folder.

Note that this setting varies for your current Build type (Debug/Release/etc), so plan accordingly...

Ciao!

Comment: hi @enorl76 please suggest me any solution for the above comment? help appreciated! I tried your solution but unfortunately unable to locate this option in VS 2013 professional edition. :(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE i have VS 2013, and I just looked and its the same.  Perhaps you are trying to use a different project type?  You have to be using a Web Application project type.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the differences between [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

> To deploy a Web application project, you copy the assembly that is
>   created by compiling the project to an IIS server. In contrast, to
>   deploy a Web site project, you typically copy the project source files
>   to an IIS server.
>
> For Web application projects, you typically build the project in
>   Visual Studio or by using the ASP.NET batch compiler on a computer
>   that is not the production IIS server. All code-behind class files and
>   standalone class files in the project are compiled into a single
>   assembly, which is then put in the Web application project's Bin
>   folder. (The .aspx and .ascx files are compiled dynamically in a
>   manner similar to what is done for Web site projects.)
>
> For Web site projects, you do not have to manually compile the
>   project. Web site projects are typically compiled dynamically by
>   ASP.NET (on both the development computer and the production IIS
>   server). You can choose between batch compilation mode, which
>   typically produces one assembly per folder, and fixed compilation
>   mode, which typically produces one assembly for each page or user
>   control.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2013/2015, select an option "Precompile during publishing" [image]