# Issue in publish ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to publish the Asp.Net MVC application. But when i publish the application, the code files are not converted as dll. The published folder contains all .cs files.

Can you please let me know how to publish the project without .cs files?

Answer (score 2):

**For Visual Studio 2012:**

After open Publish Web window, go to ***"Settings"*** tab.

Here you find "***File Publish Options***"

Check the "***Precompile during publishing***" checkbox

I think now you can publish this successfully

**For Visual 2010:**

Check this link : [Why Visual Studio 2010 publish website with source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632794/why-visual-studio-2010-publish-website-with-source-code)

Comment: Hi,
I am not able to find the "File Publish Options" in setting menu. Can you please let me how to check this?

Comment: do you use Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Oh i am sorry, this solution is for Visual Studio 2012.
I think this link will be helpful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632794/why-visual-studio-2010-publish-website-with-source-code